# Binary search tree memory errors

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I'm implementing a basic BST in C. It seems as though my insertion function is working although I'm getting errors when using Memcheck such as:

```
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x4009EF: bst_insert (bst.c:45)
==7839==    by 0x400A0D: bst_insert (bst.c:65)
==7839==    by 0x4007A5: main (bst-test.c:22)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x4009EF: bst_insert (bst.c:45)
==7839==    by 0x400A2B: bst_insert (bst.c:61)
==7839==    by 0x4007B2: main (bst-test.c:23)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x4009EF: bst_insert (bst.c:45)
==7839==    by 0x400A0D: bst_insert (bst.c:65)
==7839==    by 0x400A0D: bst_insert (bst.c:65)
==7839==    by 0x4007BF: main (bst-test.c:24)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x4009EF: bst_insert (bst.c:45)
==7839==    by 0x400A2B: bst_insert (bst.c:61)
==7839==    by 0x400A0D: bst_insert (bst.c:65)
==7839==    by 0x4007CC: main (bst-test.c:25)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x4009EF: bst_insert (bst.c:45)
==7839==    by 0x400A0D: bst_insert (bst.c:65)
==7839==    by 0x400A2B: bst_insert (bst.c:61)
==7839==    by 0x4007D9: main (bst-test.c:26)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x4009EF: bst_insert (bst.c:45)
==7839==    by 0x400A2B: bst_insert (bst.c:61)
==7839==    by 0x400A2B: bst_insert (bst.c:61)
==7839==    by 0x4007E6: main (bst-test.c:27)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x4009AF: bst_inorder (bst.c:30)
==7839==    by 0x4009C3: bst_inorder (bst.c:35)
==7839==    by 0x4009C3: bst_inorder (bst.c:35)
==7839==    by 0x4009C3: bst_inorder (bst.c:35)
==7839==    by 0x400807: main (bst-test.c:29)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x4009D0: bst_inorder (bst.c:30)
==7839==    by 0x4009C3: bst_inorder (bst.c:35)
==7839==    by 0x4009C3: bst_inorder (bst.c:35)
==7839==    by 0x400807: main (bst-test.c:29)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x4009AF: bst_inorder (bst.c:30)
==7839==    by 0x4009C3: bst_inorder (bst.c:35)
==7839==    by 0x4009C3: bst_inorder (bst.c:35)
==7839==    by 0x400807: main (bst-test.c:29)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x4009D0: bst_inorder (bst.c:30)
==7839==    by 0x4009C3: bst_inorder (bst.c:35)
==7839==    by 0x400807: main (bst-test.c:29)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x4009AF: bst_inorder (bst.c:30)
==7839==    by 0x4009C3: bst_inorder (bst.c:35)
==7839==    by 0x400807: main (bst-test.c:29)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x4009D0: bst_inorder (bst.c:30)
==7839==    by 0x400807: main (bst-test.c:29)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x400A7F: bst_preorder (bst.c:77)
==7839==    by 0x400A98: bst_preorder (bst.c:84)
==7839==    by 0x400A98: bst_preorder (bst.c:84)
==7839==    by 0x400A98: bst_preorder (bst.c:84)
==7839==    by 0x400825: main (bst-test.c:31)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x400AA0: bst_preorder (bst.c:77)
==7839==    by 0x400A98: bst_preorder (bst.c:84)
==7839==    by 0x400A98: bst_preorder (bst.c:84)
==7839==    by 0x400825: main (bst-test.c:31)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x400A7F: bst_preorder (bst.c:77)
==7839==    by 0x400A98: bst_preorder (bst.c:84)
==7839==    by 0x400A98: bst_preorder (bst.c:84)
==7839==    by 0x400825: main (bst-test.c:31)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x400AA0: bst_preorder (bst.c:77)
==7839==    by 0x400A98: bst_preorder (bst.c:84)
==7839==    by 0x400825: main (bst-test.c:31)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x400A7F: bst_preorder (bst.c:77)
==7839==    by 0x400A98: bst_preorder (bst.c:84)
==7839==    by 0x400825: main (bst-test.c:31)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x400AA0: bst_preorder (bst.c:77)
==7839==    by 0x400825: main (bst-test.c:31)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x400AD4: bst_search (bst.c:91)
==7839==    by 0x400B38: dosearch (bst-test.c:10)
==7839==    by 0x400850: main (bst-test.c:34)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x400AD4: bst_search (bst.c:91)
==7839==    by 0x400B38: dosearch (bst-test.c:10)
==7839==    by 0x40085D: main (bst-test.c:35)
==7839== 
==7839== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==7839==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7839==    by 0x400980: bst_free (bst.c:21)
==7839==    by 0x40087F: main (bst-test.c:38)
==7839==  Address 0x400dfe is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==7839== 
==7839== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==7839==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7839==    by 0x400980: bst_free (bst.c:21)
==7839==    by 0x400989: bst_free (bst.c:22)
==7839==    by 0x40087F: main (bst-test.c:38)
==7839==  Address 0x400d9f is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==7839== 
==7839== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==7839==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7839==    by 0x400980: bst_free (bst.c:21)
==7839==    by 0x400989: bst_free (bst.c:22)
==7839==    by 0x400989: bst_free (bst.c:22)
==7839==    by 0x40087F: main (bst-test.c:38)
==7839==  Address 0x400da3 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x400977: bst_free (bst.c:17)
==7839==    by 0x400989: bst_free (bst.c:22)
==7839==    by 0x400989: bst_free (bst.c:22)
==7839==    by 0x400989: bst_free (bst.c:22)
==7839==    by 0x40087F: main (bst-test.c:38)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x400977: bst_free (bst.c:17)
==7839==    by 0x400992: bst_free (bst.c:23)
==7839==    by 0x400989: bst_free (bst.c:22)
==7839==    by 0x400989: bst_free (bst.c:22)
==7839==    by 0x40087F: main (bst-test.c:38)
==7839== 
==7839== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==7839==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7839==    by 0x400980: bst_free (bst.c:21)
==7839==    by 0x400992: bst_free (bst.c:23)
==7839==    by 0x400989: bst_free (bst.c:22)
==7839==    by 0x40087F: main (bst-test.c:38)
==7839==  Address 0x400de5 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x400977: bst_free (bst.c:17)
==7839==    by 0x400989: bst_free (bst.c:22)
==7839==    by 0x400992: bst_free (bst.c:23)
==7839==    by 0x400989: bst_free (bst.c:22)
==7839==    by 0x40087F: main (bst-test.c:38)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x400977: bst_free (bst.c:17)
==7839==    by 0x400992: bst_free (bst.c:23)
==7839==    by 0x400992: bst_free (bst.c:23)
==7839==    by 0x400989: bst_free (bst.c:22)
==7839==    by 0x40087F: main (bst-test.c:38)
==7839== 
==7839== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==7839==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7839==    by 0x400980: bst_free (bst.c:21)
==7839==    by 0x400992: bst_free (bst.c:23)
==7839==    by 0x40087F: main (bst-test.c:38)
==7839==  Address 0x400da1 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==7839== 
==7839== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==7839==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7839==    by 0x400980: bst_free (bst.c:21)
==7839==    by 0x400989: bst_free (bst.c:22)
==7839==    by 0x400992: bst_free (bst.c:23)
==7839==    by 0x40087F: main (bst-test.c:38)
==7839==  Address 0x400da5 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x400977: bst_free (bst.c:17)
==7839==    by 0x400989: bst_free (bst.c:22)
==7839==    by 0x400989: bst_free (bst.c:22)
==7839==    by 0x400992: bst_free (bst.c:23)
==7839==    by 0x40087F: main (bst-test.c:38)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x400977: bst_free (bst.c:17)
==7839==    by 0x400992: bst_free (bst.c:23)
==7839==    by 0x400989: bst_free (bst.c:22)
==7839==    by 0x400992: bst_free (bst.c:23)
==7839==    by 0x40087F: main (bst-test.c:38)
==7839== 
==7839== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==7839==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7839==    by 0x400980: bst_free (bst.c:21)
==7839==    by 0x400992: bst_free (bst.c:23)
==7839==    by 0x400992: bst_free (bst.c:23)
==7839==    by 0x40087F: main (bst-test.c:38)
==7839==  Address 0x400da7 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x400977: bst_free (bst.c:17)
==7839==    by 0x400989: bst_free (bst.c:22)
==7839==    by 0x400992: bst_free (bst.c:23)
==7839==    by 0x400992: bst_free (bst.c:23)
==7839==    by 0x40087F: main (bst-test.c:38)
==7839== 
==7839== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7839==    at 0x400977: bst_free (bst.c:17)
==7839==    by 0x400992: bst_free (bst.c:23)
==7839==    by 0x400992: bst_free (bst.c:23)
==7839==    by 0x400992: bst_free (bst.c:23)
==7839==    by 0x40087F: main (bst-test.c:38)
==7839== 
==7839== 
==7839== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7839==     in use at exit: 224 bytes in 14 blocks
==7839==   total heap usage: 14 allocs, 7 frees, 224 bytes allocated
==7839== 
==7839== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7839==    definitely lost: 80 bytes in 8 blocks
==7839==    indirectly lost: 144 bytes in 6 blocks
==7839==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7839==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7839==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7839== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==7839== 
==7839== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7839== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==7839== ERROR SUMMARY: 39 errors from 35 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Here is my implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mylib.h"
#include "bst.h"

struct bstnode {

  char *key;
  bst left;
  bst right;

};

bst bst_free(bst b) {

  if (b == NULL) {

    return b;
  }
  free(b->key);
  bst_free(b->left);
  bst_free(b->right);

  return b;
}

void bst_inorder(bst b, void f(char *str)) {

  if (NULL == b) {

    return;
  }

  bst_inorder(b->left, f);

  f(b->key);

  bst_inorder(b->right, f);

}

bst bst_insert(bst b, char *str) {

  if (b == NULL) {

    bst result = emalloc(sizeof *result);
    result->key = str;

    return result;
  }

  if (strcmp(b->key, str) == 0) {

    return b;
  }

  if (strcmp(b->key, str) < 0) {

    b->right = bst_insert(b->right, str);
    return b;
  }

  b->left = bst_insert(b->left, str);
  return b;

}

bst bst_new() {

  return NULL;
}

void bst_preorder(bst b, void f(char *str)) {

  if (NULL == b) {

    return;
  }

  f(b->key);

  bst_preorder(b->left, f);
  bst_preorder(b->right, f);

}

int bst_search(bst b, char *str) {

  if (NULL == b) {

    return 0;
  }

  if (strcmp(b->key, str) == 0) {

    return 1;
  }

  if (strcmp(b->key, str) < 0) {

    return bst_search(b->right, str);
  }

  return bst_search(b->left, str);

}
```

I have another file that just tests it and my output is as expected but I'm not too sure why
I'm getting these messages. Here is the file I use to check my BST:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bst.h"

void print_key(char *key) {
  printf("%s\n", key);
}

void dosearch(bst b, char *key) {
  if (bst_search(b, key) == 0) {
    printf("%s -- not found\n", key);
  } else {
    printf("%s -- found\n", key);
  }
}

int main(void) {

  bst b = bst_new();
  printf("inserting d,b,f,a,c,e,g\n");
  b = bst_insert(b, "d");
  b = bst_insert(b, "b");
  b = bst_insert(b, "f");
  b = bst_insert(b, "a");
  b = bst_insert(b, "c");
  b = bst_insert(b, "e");
  b = bst_insert(b, "g");
  printf("inorder traversal\n");
  bst_inorder(b, print_key);
  printf("preorder traversal\n");
  bst_preorder(b, print_key);
  printf("searching\n");
  dosearch(b, "f");
  dosearch(b, "o");
  dosearch(b, "x");
  dosearch(b, "e");
  dosearch(b, "d");
  bst_free(b);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: Which lines in `bst.c` is line 45 and 65? Can you please mark them out?

Comment: Please show the definition of the `bst` type.

Comment: 45 is the first line of code under bst_insert, 65 is the last line of code in bst_insert

Comment: `result->left = result->right = NULL;` in `bst_insert` certainly seems like a plausible idea. And why does `bst_free` return *anything*? Shouldn't you actually free the `b` itself?

Comment: Is it fine to use the code: result->key = emalloc(sizeof *str); strcpy(result->key, str);

Comment: @Paldan `sizeof *str` wrong.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't know about this `emalloc` function you use, normal `malloc` doesn't initialize the memory it allocate, which means that the `left` and `right` pointers will not be initialized. Using these uninitialized pointers leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The solution? Simply set these pointers to `NULL` after allocation.

Comment: Also the `b->key` pointer seems fishy, generally you'd want a hard copy of the string, and not just a pointer to a string literal in the caller. Especially not a non-const pointer to a string literal...

Comment: I see I completely forgot about initializing the left and right. That solves one problem. I think my last problem is in my free method. One of my errors are: Address 0x400e0e is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Comment: @Paldan Well that's because you don't allocate memory for `key`, you just store a pointer to a string literal. And as you don't allocate memory for `key` you should not attempt to free it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you defined 'bst' as like below :

```
typedef struct bstnode *bst;
```

I think there is a problem in bst_insert().
You did only alloc memory for pointer variable for bst_node.

```
bst result = emalloc(sizeof *result);
```

You have to alloc memory for bst_node itself and key of bst_node.
The below code is partial for solving problem.

```
bst bst_insert(bst b, char *str) {
    if (b == NULL) {
    {
        bst result = emalloc(sizeof(struct bstnode));
        result->left = null;
        result->right = null;
        result->key = emalloc(strlen(str) + 1);
        strcpy(result->key, str);

        return result;
    }
    .....
}
```